# I'm trying out Kendo-Scroll-view with angular and facing issues with the same

Tags: angular-kendo

I am trying to use the angular-kendo scrollview and am clueless on how to start over it. Found a few examples on angular-kendo charts but none on angular-kendo scrollview. Need help!!

Thanks.